# How to provide mock data for Apiary Mock Server?

Tags: mocking, apiary.io, apiary, mockserver

**[apiary](https://apiary.io/)** service provides Mock Server, that is generated based on API description written either in API Blueprint or Swagger syntax.

In my API description I have an action returning collection of data. This collection is large, so there is filtering and pagination over it. Apiary gives me Mock Server. But this Mock Server returns collection with only 1 result for that action.

The question is how do I provide more data for the Mock Server? The idea is to develop frontend application without real server until it's ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the only data that the Apiary Mock Server can return, it's exclusively the one provided into the API description document.

However, you have complete freedom around the shape, size and format of the data, so it should be perfectly possible to return huge amounts of data as well with paginations and other things. You might want to elaborate more.